# Proof for Convergence of complex series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Hi i am looking for someone for clarification regarding a step in a proof that lies between Real and Complex Analysis.

I have the following:

For a complex sequence $(z_n)$, 
$z_n\to (z)$ iff $\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z_n)\to$ $\Im(z_n)$.

Proof: First we show that if $z_n\to z$ as $n\to \infty$, then $\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)$ and  $\Im(z_n)\to$ $\Im(z_n)$.

By definition $|z_n-z|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Using the inequality $|\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)|$ $\leq$ $|z_n-z|$and the Sandwich theorem, 
we find that $|\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)|$ as $n\to \infty$ (and similarly to show that $\Im(z_n)\to$ $\Im(z_n)$).

Hence $\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)$.

Conversely, if $\Re(z_n)\to$ $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z_n)\to$ $\Im(z_n)$ then given $\epsilon>0$ let $N$ be such that for all $n>N$ we have $|\Re(z_n)-$ $\Re(z)|<\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{2}}$ and $|\Im(z_n)-\Im(z_n)|<\frac\epsilon{\sqrt{2}}$

Thus, $|z_n-z|$$=$ $\sqrt{{|\Re(z_n)-\Re(z)|^2+|\Im(z_n)-\Im(z_n)|^2}}$ $<$$\sqrt{\frac1{2}{\epsilon^2}+\frac1{2}{\epsilon^2}}$$=$ $\epsilon$

,as required.

I have just started both Real and Complex Analysis so will take the opportunity to ask where does the $\sqrt{2}$ (second-last line above) come from as it looks like arbitrary numbers appears quite a lot the same way in analysis but i never fully understood why really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that
$$|\Re(z_n)-\Re(z)|<\delta\quad\hbox{and}\quad |\Im(z_n)-\Im(z)|<\delta\ .$$
Then
$$\sqrt{{|\Re(z_n)-\Re(z)|^2+|\Im(z_n)-\Im(z)|^2}}<\sqrt{2\delta^2}=\sqrt2\,\delta\ .$$
Since you want the LHS to be less than $\epsilon$, you would like to choose $\delta$ such that $\sqrt2\,\delta=\epsilon$, that is,
$$\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt2}\ .$$

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

$\big(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2+\big(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2=\epsilon^2$ underneath the square root in the last line. Many of these numbers in so-called $\delta$-$\epsilon$ style proofs come from reverse-engineering to get a nice $\epsilon$ at the end; other textbooks in fact do things like setting the bounds less than $\epsilon$ and ending the proof, consequently, with $\sqrt{2} \epsilon$ which accomplishes the same job as $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small.